Getting aggregate function Mode2 while groupby in python
I'm trying to compute mode 2 (second most repeated value) while groupby. I hadn't any problem for computing mode 1, but same logic doesn't work for mode 2.
grouped_df_multiple = fact_price_pt.groupby(['COD_BANDERA', 'des_product', 'dat_price'], as_index = False).agg({
'calc_pvp': ['mean', 'min', 'max', lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0] ,lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0]],
'DES_BANDERA': ['max']})

I have tried with getting second value of results of mode() like this:
lambda x: x.mode().iloc[1]

and
lambda x: x.value_counts(ascending=True).index[1]

But it doesn't work, showing the next message:

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

What should i do? Any solution?

You could use a custom function to return the nth node if it exists:
def get_nth_mode(s, n=0):
    modes =  s.mode()
    return modes.iloc[n] if n < len(modes) else None

Then in your groupby:
.agg([lambda x: get_nth_mode(x, n=1)])

Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('AAAAAABB'), 'value': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]})

df.groupby('group')['value'].agg(lambda x: get_nth_mode(x, n=1))

group
A    2.0
B    NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64

